# How do I tell TypeScript that two variables have the same type?

Tags: typescript

I have a few classes that all have the same function with a parameter that takes itself:

```
class Foo {
    someProp: number;
    constructor() {
        this.someProp = 5;
    }

    takesSelf(x: Foo | number) {}
}

class Bar {
    someProp: string;
    constructor() {
        this.someProp = "string";
    }

    takesSelf(x: Bar | string) {}
}
```

Now I have two variables, of which I know that both are the same type, both are either `Foo` or `Bar`, the two types will never be mixed. But if I call `takesSelf` I get a type error.

```
const typeA = new Bar() as Foo | Bar;
const typeB = new Bar() as Foo | Bar;
typeA.takesSelf(typeB);
//              ^^^^^----- Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'Bar'
```

Which makes sense, because TypeScript doesn't know these two variables will always share the same type.

How can I tell TypeScript these two variables will have the same type, while keeping things type safe?

For context, here's how I'm ending up with a situation of two variables that are known to both have the same type:

```
const fooBarMap = new Map<number, Foo | Bar>();

function assertIsSameType(a: Foo | Bar, b: Foo | Bar) {
    if (!(a instanceof b.constructor)) {
        throw new Error("a and b are not of the same type");
    }
}

function passAToB(a: number, b: number) {
    const typeA = fooBarMap.get(a);
    const typeB = fooBarMap.get(b);

    if (!typeA || !typeB) return;
    assertIsSameType(typeA, typeB);

    typeA.takesSelf(typeB);
    //              ^^^^^----- Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'Bar'
}
```

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoAkBeBbApgAoBO8ADgFzQB2ArrgEb7EDcGmw81EALsbcB7xiACgCUKdph4ALAJYQAdDgIly0ALzQArGywBfDOx5gA1vggBlfCABmIgB5UESAD416TYhOSH0fjFBIGAAhMGJJLBUiUkpoXmI5agBzPQ4uBIEhUR8pWQVlPBj1LQAiBKTk0rSArBNzKxt7J2gwiPcKlJ8-Ws5uHmhbRDaAWTAyTRp8AHdoMbIAHjpGZgAaOERodzaAPnE9DFtaakE5Lmhg5h4ASSswAgAVAE8yfBEwZ03t8PWGT7dWuFclg5LZoCIAITvaBJXhgE74eBghiKPqZQTCMTAzDSGSkWbUGbQACixFIolKYAu1AAJtAGBdiPgaPABkjoLJmRB7syeC98KUxDUMLUjiceGdqNAyMEAIIPeAhd5UZZeX4qzzMbFogZ816yyZDRXheaKZL4HjvIXsHUc-khQ3DE3jM0WkQMa3odig8EQvX4A2udx++0SJk8WjEahpS7EG53R78kT+2Xrf0hT3GfmyxT1CzWOzJ0NpAD0JegFcrVarAD063WALRNpvQZ6vaAAchcHZhMGorIuUDkyWoYAYIF5SH9nbaHZFRnQZegAAl4LMaUhrtAJwM2-hLMBEmQBqZ+7MAAYp8-UumX+3X6ZyEAgC4gaZgJ4wJjQdmc+I8u1XgAfgXMsHnkFIYC3Pg5HwGkKECDJdWzSZCVmNpxEHDYATaPRbXTVCiQwiRIGwrZAVYRD+mgYBIB4PcDS0FMsP9X97TwpCaLovcHSY+0WP5Nj9Tw7js1zMx8yaItXgzFhoCXftXgwFNxIaAt7Fo3geKFeTy0U-BAlE-VVMkwtNPo4tdNfHAWSUr17LFU5znNQlEmAWBqAWB5oHwBweHwWkYBccjdmVVt1VbbEwBMxpCw9OSl14J8X2YckYAoER53QFzmDkdzqGkgM02LBdDmOJypVjHhLB5MLgu+YgIvqiiJCoKqYCpBRAMRZEUFqKqaoIQrU262TlLEvNYvsdMdKXdroA3Fl8hSaAKBLUrF3LcCuumYRTAgX5aF1eQYC6qkmRpAQ4J8hx7jICdFAwJcRieaAmTAF9OBpZk+hMWELm3AdcGEH7wCgbqYBs-IYEfZ9oHNAZaGSEBXoAR1oPLTEe9AfWGmF+nhYAerIgAyEnRvxuEEXZFxsRUyb1MKsb-B8kAIGZXHmNhExqbBNpoDJinucJ4m2jpiaJKmpnPVqJ7ywQCIz2gLcZDAAA3ZkmRwONrqEBD0FtcyGIAJkmZjSOQBmmioRwqGOU812oCQNB2aA1fgOQaT8I3s2NmLGZmg5NoAdXkYAZF7Jb4loV4ImnblbAMg2jIDP2rcLUoQDkHh-OID6UepJ5luSVn2YW+ALGoDsBlS4RC+BplBRYIA) with an example and some failed experiments.

Comment: Without "correlated types" between different variables (which Typescript doesn't have, though there is a popular feature request for them), the only way to get something like this is to make both variables into properties of the same object, or elements of the same array, as some type like `{typeA: Foo, typeB: Foo} | {typeA: Bar, typeB: Bar}`. That said, you'll still have some problems if you write `obj.typeA.takesSelf(obj.typeB)` because one of them is in contravariant position.

Comment: Please edit the code here to be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue clearly; as written there is no error.  External playground links are great supplements but are not replacements for having a reproducible example in plaintext in the question post itself.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w24gzm) work for you?  Here we are using generics to deal with correlated types (similar to the fix at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) for the issue at [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)), so inside the function it will let you call `subj.takesSelf(obj)` and outside the function it will only let you pass in two appropriate values of the same type.  If this works for you I can write up an answer; otherwise let me know what's missing.

Comment: @jcalz sorry about that, I'm always discouraged to read questions when it's long, so I tried to keep things a short. I have clarified the question a bit more. Your approach is super close and for a second I thought it fixed my issue. But I didn't mention that `takesSelf` has multiple signatures. Which makes this approach cause errors as well unfortunately. I've updated this in the playground as well.

Comment: I'm trying not to make the question more complicated than it already is, but I should probably mention, the multiple signatures I have in my real code are not using a union like `takesSelf(x: Foo | number)`, but rather something more close to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25590#issuecomment-942782630).

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure I fully see the problem. [This code](https://tsplay.dev/m35qEw) shows that indeed the compiler will not be happy with you calling `x.takesSelf(y)` if it only knows that `x` and `y` are each `Foo | Bar`.  This is a correct error because there's no way for the compiler to know that `x` and `y` are correlated in any way.  You could jump through a lot of hoops convincing the compiler that it's okay to take a value `[x, y]` of type `[Foo, Foo] | [Bar, Bar]` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX701W), I guess.  Is it worth it to you? Type assertions are not unreasonable.

Comment: Let me know if there's anything in particular you want to see here.

Comment: @jcalz Hmm I'm not sure that many hoops is worth it for my specific situation. Right now I'm basically casting the type to `unknown`, which keeps TS quiet but isn't very type safe. I'm not working on a super important section of the application so I'm hoping tests will take care of any future issues. I appreciate the help though! I also asked this to learn more about TypeScript, and the approach you showed earlier did teach me something :)

Answer (score -1):

I hope I understood you correctly and this is your use case, if so then you can use [TS generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) for that

Ex:

```js
// This way you will have typesafe and keep DRY for this method
type TakeSelf<T extends Object> = (x: T)=> void

class Foo {
    takesSelf: TakeSelf<this>
}

class Bar {
    takesSelf: TakeSelf<this>
}
```

Comment: This is not the same as OPs code.

Comment: now it looks good, I made a playground to check: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgawgZQgGwGYB4YD4oC8UAFAB4BcsAlAfgG4D2AlgCYCwAUJwMZpwDO-KADEGDKAG9OUGVGCII-VJgCEleEmXZgACyb9cnAL6cefQVABCcAE6Tps+UiXoMa2Aq1Zd+wxxNcHNwMAHb8wHLgEACChFAhEADuVrbEVFACImJQAD4pNgDcPKHhkZCWcQnJ1jZpGUKi4nk1RRygkNEAdE6KWsTtEJZUBUA Note that I had to add the `!` in the class and removed the unnecessary `extends Object`.

Comment: Downvotes are an indication that the answer is wrong, in this case I think because you *didn't* understand what the question is asking for. Downvotes indicate to other readers who have the same problem that this answer will not help them. By the way, if you aren't sure that you have understood what the question is asking for, you should write a comment requesting clarification, instead of writing an answer and hoping it is correct.

Comment: @Clashsoft the error in the playground is due to a lack of declaration of the actual method. in OP's actual code it will run without the error mentioned, but for the sake of demonstration, you are right. thanks!

Comment: When writing example code in Typescript you have to be careful to avoid unintended structural type equivalence. In this case your code only shows no errors in the Playground because your types `Foo` and `Bar` are actually equivalent. If you give them some members so that they are different types, then you will see that you get the same error as in the OP's code. https://tsplay.dev/mL4O4m

Comment: @kaya3 sorry about that, when a question is long I'm often discouraged to read the whole thing so I tried to keep things short. I've updated the question with some extra details about the situation.